# Editing a CSV Header

Tags: powershell, csv

I've got a requirement. As part of which, I'm trying to export the ACLs on an Exchange mailbox to a CSV and importing it a bit later. One of the attribute on Exchange mailbox permissions is an array so our CSV header has `$_.AccessRights` as the array's header since we use `Select {$_.AccessRights}` to export this array.

The problem arises when importing because `Import-Csv` won't like this. I'm trying to find a way to edit just the `$_.` out of the header only for that attribute and re-write the file before importing it again. Have tried `Import-Csv -Header` and `Get-Object` with `-replace` with no luck so far. Any other thoughts?

Edit: I'm actually not just trying to do `Import-Csv` but actually trying to run run `Add-MailboxPermission` - Exchange script to import ACLs on a mailbox. So, the code I'm trying to run is

```
Import-Csv $ACLExportFile | foreach { Add-MailboxPermission -Identity $_.Identity -user $_.user -AccessRights $_.AccessRights | Out-File $LogACLImport -append }
```

Where $ACLExportFile is the permissions file I exported earlier using

```
Get-Mailbox -identity $OldUser | Get-MailboxPermission | Select {$_.AccessRights}, Deny, InheritanceType, User, Identity, IsInherited, IsValid | Export-Csv $ACLExportFile
```

Sample file that I got is 
[Uploaded to Google Drive here](https://goo.gl/qGHm07)

Comment: can you post your script?

Comment: Can't reproduce. `Import-Csv` imports a CSV with a header `$_.AccessRights` just fine. Please provide evidence (code and full error message).

Comment: As well as a sample of your csv for testing!

Comment: Thanks for both your help Ansgar and Matt. @JPBlanc Updated my question to add some info.

Comment: @MuthukumarP I edit my answer to show you where to use the property parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure to understand the question.
Have a look to [Select-Object](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849895.aspx) CmdLet, you can provide a property parameter that can be a new calculated property. To create a calculated, property, use a hash table. Valid keys are:
-- Name (or Label) 
-- Expression  or

```
-Property @{Name="AccessRights";Expression={$_.AccessRights}}
```

Edit :
In you case, when you export you should use :

```
Get-Mailbox -identity $OldUser | Get-MailboxPermission | Select @{Name="AccessRights"; Expression={$_.AccessRights}}, Deny, InheritanceType, User, Identity, IsInherited, IsValid | Export-Csv $ACLExportFile
```

So that you can import like this :

```
Import-Csv $ACLExportFile | foreach { Add-MailboxPermission -Identity $_.Identity -user $_.user -AccessRights $_.AccessRights | Out-File $LogACLImport -append }
```

Comment: Thanks. @JPBlanc. I've tried the `Select-Object` but it generated an empty file.

Comment: @MuthukumarP, you should edit your question and add your code if you want more help.

Comment: THanks @JPBlanc. That sorted my issue :)